# Thin server with AWS Elastic Beanstalk issue

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, thin

I'm trying to move a Sinatra App that uses Thin server from Heroku to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The issue at the moment is that Nginx is looking for a Puma server instead of Thin:

```
connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Is it possible to use Thin AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Did you set up Elastic Beanstalk with the Passenger platform or the Puma platform for Ruby? I'm wondering if you set it up with Puma, and you should be using Passenger instead.

Comment: It's Puma now. Trying to change the nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get Thin server running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with the files below. Turning off Puma server is not yet working.

**.ebextensions\01_nginx.config**

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_set_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/run/thin"
      su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/log/thin"
      chown -R $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER /var/run/thin
      chown -R $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER /var/log/thin

  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_app_server.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # The content of this file is based on the content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf

      upstream my_app_new {
        least_conn;
        server unix:///var/run/thin/thin.0.sock;
        server unix:///var/run/thin/thin.1.sock;
      }

      log_format healthd_new '$msec"$uri"'
                      '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd_new;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://my_app_new; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /public {
          alias /var/app/current/public;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        client_max_body_size 0;
      }

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      directory '/var/app/current'
      threads 0
      workers 0
      bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'
      pidfile '/var/run/puma/puma.pid'
      stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma.log', true
      daemonize false

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_start_rhoconnect.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Loading environment data
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
      # Setting up correct environment and ruby version so that bundle can load all gems
      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh
      # Stop Puma
      # su -s /bin/bash -c "pumactl -P /var/run/puma/puma.pid stop" $EB_APP_USER
      # Now we can do the actual restart of the server. Make sure to have double quotes when using env vars in the command.
      cd $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR
      FILE=/var/run/thin/thin.pid
      if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
          su -s /bin/bash -c "RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin restart -R config.ru -e production -p 9292 -C config/thin.yml" $EB_APP_USER
      else
          su -s /bin/bash -c "RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 9292 -C config/thin.yml" $EB_APP_USER
      fi

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
  02_remove_webapp_healthd:
    command: "rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf"
```

**config\thin.yml:**

```
---
chdir: /var/app/current
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: /var/log/thin/thin.log
pid: /var/run/thin/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
wait: 30
threadpool_size: 20
daemonize: true
socket: /var/run/thin/thin.sock
servers: 2
```

**.ebextensions\tail-logs.config**

```
files:
 "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/cloud-init.conf" :
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    /var/log/thin/thin.0.log
    /var/log/thin/thin.1.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user2666194's excellent answer, I found that EB would complain about being in a degraded state due to the application not running.

It appears `healthd` checks the pid listed in `/var/elasticbeanstalk/healthd/application.pid` to ensure the application is running. This by default is linked to `/var/run/puma/puma.pid`.

To combat this, I modified the `01_nginx.config` file to remove and replace this pid. I also added the `initctl` command to stop puma. Now we're checking the right pid, this appears to have no ill effects:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_set_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/run/thin"
      su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /var/log/thin"
      chown -R $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER /var/run/thin
      chown -R $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER /var/log/thin
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_app_server.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # The content of this file is based on the content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf

      upstream my_app {
        least_conn;
        server unix:///var/run/thin/thin.0.sock;
        server unix:///var/run/thin/thin.1.sock;
      }

      log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                      '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          # Application is 180, this is overhead
          proxy_read_timeout 200s;
        }

        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /public {
          alias /var/app/current/public;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        client_max_body_size 0;
      }

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      directory '/var/app/current'
      threads 0
      workers 0
      bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'
      pidfile '/var/run/puma/puma.pid'
      stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma.log', true
      daemonize false

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_start_thin.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Loading environment data
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
      # Setting up correct environment and ruby version so that bundle can load all gems
      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh
      # Stop Puma
      /sbin/initctl stop puma
      # Now we can do the actual restart of the server. Make sure to have double quotes when using env vars in the command.
      cd $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR
      FILE=/var/run/thin/thin.pid
      if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
          su -s /bin/bash -c "RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin restart -R config.ru -e production -p 9292 -C config/thin.yml" $EB_APP_USER
      else
          su -s /bin/bash -c "RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 9292 -C config/thin.yml" $EB_APP_USER
      fi
      # Remove the old app pid (puma) and replace it with our one
      rm -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/healthd/application.pid
      ln -s /var/run/thin/thin.0.pid /var/elasticbeanstalk/healthd/application.pid

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
  02_remove_webapp_healthd:
    command: "rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf"
```